# lightning web component datatable create new record

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightning web component wrapped in an aura component. When the user selects the quick action it renders a datatable of the child records(po lines) 
Right now if if a user selects more than 1 row it creates multiple records. I would like it to create 1 invoice and how many rows selected would be the number of inv line items(child of Inv) created .
Right now it create multiple records if more than 1 row is selected. So if I could get some help on the LWC and class.
This is what I have so far:

```
<template>
<lightning-button label="Create Invoice" onclick={handleRowAction}></lightning-button><br/><br/>
<lightning-datatable 
  key-field="Id"    
  data={polineitems.data}
  columns={columns} 
  is-loading={tableLoadingState}
  oncellchange={handleCellchange}
  draft-values={draftValues}
  errors={errors}
</lightning-datatable>
```

```
import { LightningElement, wire,track } from 'lwc';
import getPoLineItemList from 
'@salesforce/apex/InvLineItemCreate.getPoLineItemList';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

const columns = [
{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' , editable: false },
{ label: 'Total', fieldName: 'Total_Invoice_Amt__c', type: 'text', editable: 
false },
  { label: 'Inv Amount', fieldName: 'Invoice_Amt__c', type: 'number', editable: 
true },
  { label: 'Total Cost', fieldName: 'Total_Cost__c', type: 'number', editable: 
false },
];

export default class CreateInvFromPO extends LightningElement {
@track polineitems = [];
@track data = [];
@track draftValues = [];
@track columns = columns;
@track errors;
@track selectedFieldsValue='';

error;
columns = columns;
@wire(getPoLineItemList)
polineitems;

getRowData(rowId) {
    for (let row of this.polineitems.data) {
        if (rowId == row.Id) {
            return row;
        }
    }
}

handleCellchange(event) {
    const rowId = event.detail.draftValues[0].Id
    console.log("draftValues = ", JSON.stringify(event.detail.draftValues[0]));
    console.log(rowId);
    console.log(this.getRowData(rowId).Total_Cost__c);
  //  console.log("fieldValues = ", JSON.stringify(event.detail.fieldName[0]));
    const Invoice_Amt__c = parseFloat(event.detail.draftValues[0].Invoice_Amt__c)
   // console.log("Inv Amt = ", parseFloat(event.detail.draftValues[0].Invoice_Amt__c));
   // const Invoice_Amt__c = parseFloat(this.data.filter(dat => dat.id === rowId)[0].Invoice_Amt__c);

   //another validation attempt 
   let editDraftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
   let validationError = false;

   this.errors = { rows: {}, table: {} };

   editDraftValues.forEach(editDraft => {
        let validationerrorfound = false;

        if (Invoice_Amt__c  > this.getRowData(rowId).Total_Cost__c) 
        {
               validationError = true;
               this.errors.rows[editDraft.Id] =  { title: "Error updating Inv Amount", messages: ["Enter a value less than Total invoice amount"] };
         }
   });
   if (validationError)
   {
       return;
   }

}

const selectedRows = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').getSelectedRows();
    const selectedIds = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Id);
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Total_Cost__c);
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Invoice_Amt__c);
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Total_Invoice_Amt__c);
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Purchase_Order__r.Name);
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Name);
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Purchase_Order__c);


        let totalcost;
        totalcost = selectedRows[i].Total_Cost__c;
        let poid;
        poid = selectedRows[i].Id;
        let totalinv;
        totalinv = selectedRows[i].Total_Invoice_Amt__c;
        let invamt;
        invamt = selectedRows[i].Invoice_Amt__c;
        let poiname;
        poiname = selectedRows[i].Name;
        let poname;
        poname = selectedRows[i].Purchase_Order__r.Name;
        let PO;
        PO = selectedRows[i].Purchase_Order__c;

        let inv = { 'sobjectType': 'Invoice__c' };
        inv.Name= 'INV-' + poname;//selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Name);
        inv.Purchase_Order_Line__c =poid;  ///selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Id);
        inv.Total_Invoice_Amount__c =invamt ; ///selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Invoice_Amt__c);
        inv.Purchase_Order__c= PO;

        console.log(inv.Total_Invoice_Amount__c);
        console.log("Sobject: " + inv );

        createInvRecord({newRecord: inv})
        .then(result => {
            this.recordId = result;
            console.log("results: " + result);
            return refreshApex(this.selectedRows);
            return refreshApex(inv);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("error: " +error);
            this.error = error;
        });
    } 
} 


handleSave(event) {
    const recordInputs =  event.detail.draftValues.slice().map(draft => {
        const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
        return { fields };
    });

    const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));


    Promise.all(promises).then(polineitems => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'PO line Item Updated',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
         this.draftValues = [];

         return refreshApex(this.polineitems);
    }).catch(error => {

    });
}
```

Apex class.

```
public with sharing class InvLineItemCreateFromPO {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Purchase_Order_Line__c> getPoLineItemList()  {
 return [SELECT Name,Invoice_Amt__c,Total_Invoice_Amt__c, Purchase_Order__r.Name, Line_Description__c,Quantity__c, Unit_Cost__c,
        Total_Cost__c FROM Purchase_Order_Line__c];
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String createInvRecord(Invoice__c newRecord) {
    insert newRecord;
    return newRecord.Id;
}
```

}

P

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a spin through our [Tour] and read [ask], then [edit] your question to show what you've done so far and include a *specific, detailed* question the community can answer.

Comment: I read this thread https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273550/how-to-get-selected-row-data-from-lightning-datatable-in-salesforce-lwc and have added it to my LWC jc. But I am unsure on how to take the selected rows and create a new record. Most thing I have read reference how to create a new record from form and not how to create from existing record(s). <br> I have a button inline with the row -Callrowaction

Comment: {callRowAction}           
        callRowAction( event ) {   
        const recId =  event.detail.row.Id;  
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;  
        if ( actionName === 'Associates' ) {  
        how to create records?  
        }

Comment: Please **[edit] your question**.

Comment: I am sure the community can provide assistance, but you do need to [edit] your post to show a complete, detailed, specific question, including the code you've written to solve the problem so far. Please don't use comments to add details.