# How to get data from selected rows in a lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

How can I get data from a row selected in a lightning data table? I was looking at [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273550/how-to-get-selected-row-data-from-lightning-datatable-in-salesforce-lwc) but it doesn't seem like the playground linked in the answer is working so I cannot see the helper method. The first answer for that uses a custom table and I would like to stick to using the lightning datatable. Does anyone have any examples? I would like to get the recordId's of the records selected, to be specific.

Comment: were you able to get your row selection working?

Answer (score 4):

The [playground / lwc documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) has a clear code sample of how to get row selection(s):

```
    <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handleRowSelection}>
        </lightning-datatable>

    handleRowSelection(event){
            const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer that glls gave is close but not working. What does work is:

```
    <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowselection={handleRowSelection}>
     </lightning-datatable>

    handleRowSelection(event){
            const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows
    }
```

Notice that instead of `onrowaction`, the correct element is `onrowselection`.